# AHK Wrong keystroke when using controlsend

Tags: autohotkey

I'm using ControlSend to send commands to a CLI.
The CLI was opened by the cmd.

ControlSend in the cmd works okay but controlsend to the cli opened by the cmd sends the wrong keystroke.

```
ControlSend, , -allue -allcell{enter}, ahk_pid %pid2%
```

It shows up as �밶llue -allcell.
Why is this happening?

Comment: What CLI are you using? I'm trying to replicate this issue.

Comment: @Spyre I'm using moshell inside bash . Bash is opened by using cygwin.